# HTML/CSS Button Hover shifting everything else away?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

If I hover over my buttons they shift(?) other elements.

as you can see I already tried to compensate the +4 pixels from the border by subtracting them from the height and the width but the problem remains.

I don't want this. I want it to change appearance without any shifting.

[Here a video to visualize my problem](https://youtu.be/9eTTE51SoP0)

Thank you in advance :)

Here the CSS and HTML

HTML:

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo-bookmark.svg" alt="Logo nav">
    <div class="navElements">
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">Features</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">Pricing</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-logo-btn">Login</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <h1 class="header-heading">A Simple Bookmark Manager</h1>
      <p class="header-text"> A clean and simple interface to organize your favourite websites. Open a new
        browser tab and see your sites load instantly. Try it for free.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn-1">Get it on Chrome</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-2">Get it on Firefox</a>
    </div>
    <img class="header-img" src="images\illustration-hero.svg" alt="Hero image">
```

Login Button:

```
.nav-logo-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--SoftRed);
  padding: 10px 32px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.nav-logo-btn:hover {
  color: var(--SoftRed);
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Chrome/Firefox Buttons:

```
.btn-1, .btn-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 165px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-1:hover, .btn-2:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 161px;
}

.btn-1 {
  background-color: var(--SoftBlue);
  color: white;

}

.btn-2 {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #606068;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  left: 50px;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  color: var(--SoftBlue);
}

.btn-2:hover {
  color: #606068;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding 2px border on hover, use `box-shadow`. It doesn't affect the physical size of elements.

```css
.btn-1:hover, .btn-2:hover {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px var(--SoftBlue);
  height: 44px;
  width: 161px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `backface-visibility: hidden;` on your header class and it will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it but it didn't work.
I also tried it on the buttons itself and the header-left class but that also
didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option is to simply change the color of the border on hover instead of adding a border that doesn't exist most of the time.

Consider:

```css
.button {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jumpy:hover {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.smooth {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

.smooth:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="button jumpy">Jumpy Button</div>
<div class="button smooth">Smooth Button</div>
```